# Gatling simulation with fixed number of users for specific period of time

Tags: gatling

I have my Gatling scenario set up and now I want to configure a simulation with fixed number of users for specific period of time - number of users should initially be  increased gradually to specific value and then kept there by adding new as required as users finish.

I specifically don't want to use `constantUsersPerSec` (which injects users at a constant rate) but something like `.throttle(reachUsers(100) in rampUpTime, holdFor(10 minute))` which should inject users when required.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "should inject users when required"

Comment: @niharika_neo - I want number of users to be kept constant - when some users finish their scenario Gatling should inject new ones.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it's still relevant: Gatling supports a `throttle` method pretty much as you outlined it. You can use the following building blocks (taken from the [docs](http://gatling.io/docs/current/general/simulation_setup/#throttling)):

> - `reachRps(target) in (duration)`: target a throughput with a ramp over a given duration.
> - `jumpToRps(target)`: jump immediately to a given targeted throughput.
> - `holdFor(duration)`: hold the current throughput for a given duration.

So a modified example for your use case could look something like this:

```
setUp(scn.inject(constantUsersPerSec(100) during(10 minutes))).throttle(
  reachRps(100) in (1 minute),
  holdFor(9 minute)
)
```